# js file isnt found when I put it in a bundle

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Current setup in my _Layout.cshtml I have the standard script tag with file path to a few angularjs files like so.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angularjs/Controller/MyController.js"></script>...(plus a few more)
```

So instead of explicitly having all of them in the _layout file I wanted to bundle them. So I did in the BundleConfig.cs like so.

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts").Include(
 "~/angularjs/Factory/authService.js",
"~/angularjs/Controller/MyController.js"));
```

Everything builds. However when I run it, the browser console window gives me an angular error saying that it can not find my authService.js file. The official error is as follows.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=authServiceProvider%20%3C-%20authService

So my question is why when I bundle my scripts does it not see the authService file. Bear in mind if I call it explicitly, my angular and webpage works fine with no errors. (I have also messed with the order that I call them in my bundle and I still can not get the webpage to work).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: To provide a little bit of angular code here is my service.

```
(function () {

    var authService = function ($http, $q, localStorageService) {
    /*bunch of code*/
 };

    var module = angular.module("mainApp");

    module.factory("authService", authService);



}());
```

So I made the following changes but I am still getting the same error along with an additional error in the web browser of "~Scripts/angularjs" responded with 403 error.

```
(function () {

    var module = angular.module("mainApp");

    module.factory("authService", authService);

    authService.$inject("$http", "$q", "localStorageService");

    var authService = function ($http, $q, localStorageService) {
/*my code*/
};
}());
```

Final Solution:
For clarification I will post what I did in order for it to work. The key was as pointed out by @Tommaso Sebastianelli to pass in the dependencies on the line module.factory in the []. Thanks so much for the prompt response.

```
(function () {

    var authService = function ($http, $q, localStorageService) {
/*my code here*/

 };
    var module = angular.module("mainApp");

    module.factory("authService", ["$http", "$q","localStorageService", authService]);

}());
```

Comment: The error doesn't say it can't find the authservice.js file, it says that Angular is unable to find the `authService`.

Comment: I fixed my 403 error by changing the name of my bundle from "~/Scripts" to "~/angular/scripts" the reason why is because the former is an actual path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you have non explicit dependency injection in your angular service? Example:

```
yourapp.service('authService', function(dependancy1, dependancy2, etc){

});
```

This kind of error happened to me many times when minimizing and bundling modules.
If this is the case fix your code like this:

```
yourapp.service('authService', ['dependancy1', 'dependancy2', '...',
   function (dependancy1, dependancy2, etc){

}]);
```

**Best option** :

```
yourapp.service('authService', authService);

authService.$inject = ['dependency1', 'dependency2', '...'];

function authService(){
//code here
}
```